# Action in route

Tags: php, laravel

I would have liked to know if its possible to do something like that :

```
Route::post('/a/addCart/{id}', function () {
if(Auth::guest()){
    return view('a.log');
}
else{
    action('aController@aAdd');
}});
```

Instead of just :

```
Route::post('/a/addCart/{id}', 'aController@aAdd');
```

I will be grateful for any help you can provide.

Comment: why don't you put the check in the aAdd function of the aController? Or even better create a middleware?

Comment: As your code example I recommended use `middleware`

Comment: You're right thank you @GiacomoM

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

**Route** like:

```
Route::get('/a/addCart/{id}', 'aController@aAdd');
```

**Controller** function like this:

```
use Auth;

aAdd($id){

   if(!Auth::check()){
     return view('a.log');
   } else {

   }


}
```